# Generalization of simple and transfinite induction

Tags: set-theory, induction, ordinals

#### Definition

For a set of ordinals $\boldsymbol\alpha$ and ordinals $\gamma$, $\beta$, let

> $$\boldsymbol\alpha \xrightarrow[\gamma]{}\beta$$

symbolize the proposition that

> - $(\boldsymbol\alpha,<)$ has order-type $\gamma$ for the natural ordering $<$
>   [alternatively: $\boldsymbol\alpha$ is a strictly increasing $\gamma$-indexed set of ordinals]
> - $\beta \not\in \boldsymbol\alpha$
> - $\beta$ is the supremum of $\boldsymbol\alpha$

(read: "$\boldsymbol\alpha$ is a $\gamma\rightarrow\beta$-sequence").

For all $\gamma\rightarrow\beta$-sequences $\boldsymbol\alpha$ it holds that

> - $\gamma \leq \beta$
> - $\gamma$ and $\beta$ are both limit or both successor ordinals

---

#### Examples

1. $\boldsymbol\alpha \xrightarrow[1]{}\beta$ means $\boldsymbol\alpha = \lbrace \alpha \rbrace$ and $\beta = \alpha + 1$
2. $\boldsymbol\alpha \xrightarrow[\omega]{}\beta$ means $\boldsymbol\alpha$ is a countable [fundamental sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-growing_hierarchy#Definition) with limit $\beta$
3. $\boldsymbol\alpha \xrightarrow[\beta]{}\beta$ means $\boldsymbol\alpha=\beta = \lbrace \alpha : \alpha < \beta \rbrace$
4. $\boldsymbol\alpha=\beta$ implies $\boldsymbol\alpha \xrightarrow[\beta]{}\beta$

---

#### Definition

With each ordinal number $\gamma$ a second-order property $\Pi_\gamma$ of properties $P$ of ordinal numbers is associated:

> $$(\forall \beta)\ (\forall \boldsymbol\alpha
>  \xrightarrow[\gamma]{}\beta)\ \Big( \big( (\forall \alpha \in
>  \boldsymbol\alpha)\ P(\alpha)\big) \Rightarrow P(\beta)\Big)$$

This meta-property reads:

> When for an arbitrary $\beta$ all members of an arbitrary
>   $\gamma\rightarrow\beta$-sequence $\boldsymbol\alpha$ have property
>   $P$, then also $\beta$ has (= inherits) property $P$.

Compare with the parameter-free second-order property $\Pi$:

$$(\forall \beta)\ (\forall \boldsymbol\alpha \xrightarrow[\beta]{}\beta)\ \Big( \big( (\forall \alpha \in \boldsymbol\alpha)\ P(\alpha)\big) \Rightarrow P(\beta)\Big)$$

which is a blown-up way to say $(\forall \beta) \big( (\forall \alpha < \beta)\ P(\alpha)\big) \Rightarrow P(\beta)$.

---

#### Examples of usage

*[Simple induction]*
If $P(0)$ and $P$ has property $\Pi_1$ then $P(\alpha)$ for all finite ordinals $\alpha$.

*[Transfinite induction]*
If $P(0)$ and $P$ has property $\Pi$ then $P(\alpha)$ for all ordinals $\alpha$.

---

### Question

> How do generalizations with respect to properties $\Pi_\gamma$ look like?
>
> What would especially be the condition $\Phi_\omega$ in:
>
> If $P(0)$ and $P$ has property $\Pi_\omega$ then $P(\alpha)$ for all
>   ordinals $\alpha$ obeying condition $\Phi_\omega$.

Comment: Your Example 3 is not correct.  $\boldsymbol\alpha \xrightarrow[\beta]{}\beta$ can hold without $\boldsymbol\alpha$ being all of $\beta$.  For example, let  $\beta=\omega$ and let $\boldsymbol\alpha$ be the set of even natural numbers.

Comment: I gave a hopefully more correct example 4.

Comment: I think $\Pi_\gamma$-induction can be rephrased in terms of transfinite induction only along ordinals of cofinality $\le\gamma$, so $\Phi_\omega$ should be the condition "$\alpha$ is less than the least uncountable regular cardinal".